# If one meta key value is empty, try to get another meta key, and if both meta keys are empty show something else?

Tags: custom-field

I have this code:

```
<div class="video-embed" style="margin-top: 0px; z-index:102; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<?php

$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true );
$search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
$replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);

?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Now I need to implement feature...

If video_play is empty, try to get video_stop `$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_stop' , true );`, if video_play and video_stop are empty show text "This video is removed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if else:

```
<div class="video-embed" style="margin-top: 0px; z-index:102; margin-bottom: 0px;">

<?php

$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true ) ?: get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_stop' , true ) ?: false;

if( $url1 ):
    $search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
    $replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
    $url        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);

?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php 
else: 
    echo "This video is removed";
endif;    
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Never get better answer since I use internet. Thank you!

Comment: Can I apply is_user_logged_in() statement for only video_stop value somehow?

Comment: you want to get `video_stop` only if user is logged in??

Comment: `$url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true ) ?: is_user_logged_in() ? get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_stop' , true ) : false;`

Comment: Thank you. I did similar workaround too. Both ways works anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct, just added if user logged in for video_stop.

```
<div class="video-embed" style="margin-top: 0px; z-index:102; margin-bottom: 0px;">

<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   $url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true ) ?: get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_stop' , true ) ?: false;
  } else {
    $url1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'video_play' , true ) ?: false; 
  }

if( $url1 ):
    $search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
    $replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
    $url        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$url1);

?>


<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php 
else: 
    echo '<div id="removed" style="
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
background: #111;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 0px;
height: 0;
text-align: center;
"><p style="position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;">
    Video is removed!
    </a></p></div>';
endif;    
?>
</div>
```